# Selenium sendKeys does not work with an array using loop

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I made an array of special characters and want to pass these special characters to each input field by using sendKeys function. 
The below code does not work and I have no idea why.. 
I really appreciate if someone can help me solve this.

```
    String[] specialCharList = {"'",":","|","&"};

    for (int i = 0; i < specialCharList.length; i++) {


        WebElement spList1 = driver.findElement(By.id("primaryContact_firstNameCell"));
        spList1.sendKeys(specialCharList[i]);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement spList2 = driver.findElement(By.id("primaryContact_,middleInitialCell"));
        spList2.sendKeys(specialCharList[i]);
        Thread.sleep(3000);  

        WebElement spList3 = driver.findElement(By.id("primaryContact_lastNameCell"));
        spList3.sendKeys(specialCharList[i]);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Is passing in the whole string not possible?  Are you hoping for something special with those specific characters?  Please provide the actual behavior that you consider doesn't work.

Comment: I am trying to send each special character to each input field and click the save to see if it returns any error. For example, I want to send a single quote (') to each input field (such as first name and last name fields) and click a save button. And it iterates with next special character in the array that is semicolon (:) in this case. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `does not work`? Are you getting any error/exception?

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "unknown error: cannot focus element"..

Comment: Sorry guys, I found out that I was getting a wrong id... With the correct id, this code worked perfect. I am really sorry and thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in the Facebook login page and it seems to be working well.

Find the code I tried and refer to the screenshot.
Please let us know what kind of error you are getting when you are trying.

```
String[] specialCharList = {"'",":","|","&"};
    for (int i = 0; i < specialCharList.length; i++) {
        WebElement spList1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@name='firstname']"));
        spList1.sendKeys(specialCharList[i]);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement spList2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@name='lastname']"));
        spList2.sendKeys(specialCharList[i]);
        Thread.sleep(3000); 
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your screenshot. I get an error saying "unknown error: cannot focus element". Do you know what that means?

Comment: Just FYI, I am trying to test an application form on the website.

Comment: Hi Guna, I am sorry that it turned out that I was using a wrong id...and now it works perfect. I am sorry but I really appreciated your help.

Comment: About error while you opening screenshot - it is because, i m not allowed to attache screenshot in stackoverflow until i earn pretty good points in this website(LoL). I m happy that you found the solution.